# Mongoose Schema not predefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I would like to create a "free" schema. A schema where the customer can push his own key/value.

This is my Schema :

```
const balanceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: { type: String },
    incomes: { type: String },
    fees: { type: String }
})
```

I would like the customer to push in "incomes" ans "fees" categories any key: value he wants, and as much as he wants.

For example, this JSON file :

```
{
    "userId": "9450654064560845",
    "incomes": {
        "label": 2000,
        "label2": 1000,
        "label3": 500
        },
    "fees": {
        "fee1": 45,
        "mySuperFee": 300
    }
}
```

With the Schemas, I can't push something that is not in the Schema.
Any idea how ?

Comment: To save it needs key value pair defined, if you are not sure about incoming data inside incomes and fees you can use type as array, and insert object with key value inside it.

Comment: I found a solution. I set the strict mode to off. Now I can push whatever I want. Thanks !